Redragon Aurora headset strange volume behavior and microphone not working
I recently bought a Redragon Aurora and I was using it on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS without any problem.
Then, during a Google Meeting when the mic stopped working since then.
I've tried the fixes mentioned here but none of them worked.
This issue seems to be Linux-based issue, because I tested it on another computer running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and the same issue happens. But, when testing the headset on a Windows 11 machine, it works fine.
What I noticed is that on the Soud settings, the headset has two options for the headset Output, one analog and the other digital:

If I select the Analog Output - H376 then to hear anything, the volume must be at 100%. Any value below 100% the Output sound does not work.
If I change to Digital Output - H376 it works fine if and only if the Analog Outout - H376 was set to 100%, otherwise the Digital Output will not output any sound.
And the microphone, It detects the mic but it does not get any input signal on the input test bar:

UPDATE 1:
When I plug in the USB of the headset, I get these dmesg messages:
[ 1223.617915] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=3206, idProduct=4006, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1223.617921] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1223.617923] usb 3-1.3: Product: H376 USB Gaming Headset
[ 1223.617924] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer: USB Audio
[ 1223.617926] usb 3-1.3: SerialNumber: 67452312EFCD
[ 1223.642167] input: USB Audio H376 USB Gaming Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.3/0003:3206:4006.000B/input/input41
[ 1223.642262] input: USB Audio H376 USB Gaming Headset Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:38:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.3/0003:3206:4006.000B/input/input42
[ 1223.694228] hid-generic 0003:3206:4006.000B: input,hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [USB Audio H376 USB Gaming Headset] on usb-0000:38:00.0-1.3/input3
[ 1223.965273] retire_capture_urb: 128 callbacks suppressed
06:43:16 ~{note}$ 


I found this solution and it finally worked for me.
